# Why do functions auto take in code that's not apart of the function

Tags: python, python-3.x, comments, replit

The title may be confusing so I will explain it. I run python on replit.com (not sure if this is only an issue on replit.com) and sometimes when I hide then unhide code within a function it automatically puts code that's next to but not within the function inside the function. Sometimes it does this but other times it doesn't and I don't understand its reasoning. Let me show you an example:

```
def f(x): # Collapsed Function

# Comment (outside of function)
```

I open the function

```
def f(x): # Open Function
     print("Function is open")

# Comment (outside of function)
```

Then I close it

```
def f(x): # Closed Function
```

Then I reopen it

```
def f(x): # Open Function
     print("Function is open")
# Comment (Inside Function)
```

What's more odd is that the comment isn't indented yet the code acts as if the comment is within the function. This isn't the only occurrence. So here is my question: Why does this occur and how can I prevent this from happening again?

Comment: Pretty sure this is just a replit problem; I've never had this problem before on VSC. Not really python-related

Comment: you must understand, this has nothing to do with Python, this is something directly related to whatever text-editor/IDE you are using

Comment: If there's a bug with replit.com, you should report it. There's a 'Report a bug' button in the lower left '?' menu. This has nothing to do with Python and is not a question for StackOverflow. It's just a problem with a free online editor. (I was able to reproduce the issue, it always happens if there's a comment with a line break right after a function - some bug in the code deciding what is part of the function)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I will report this to replit.com.

Comment: Comments don't follow indentation rules in Python. repl.it has to guess which function the comment is related to, and it's guessing wrong.